# Method to find the quantile of a sample value given value vector in julia

Tags: statistics, julia

How do I calculate the quantile of a sample value given an array of samples in julia?
The Statistics.jl package kind of goes the other way here.

```
samples = collect(1:50)
sample = 27

quantile(samples, sample)
```

Answer (score 3):

Is:

```
julia> count(<(sample), samples)/length(samples)
0.52

julia> count(<=(sample), samples)/length(samples)
0.54
```

good enough? This is faster than calculating the median for example, since the median requires sort-like algorithm. Note the two values are relevant, depending on the exact definition of quantile you need for your application.

Comment: note that the median does not require a sort-like algorithm. It can use quickselect like any other quantile.

Comment: @OscarSmith Sure, by sort-like I meant quickselect (which uses pivoting like quicksort). It does not incur the complexity of sort, that is true (but it isn't a simple scan). It might be best to know if the underlying vector is sorted, then better algorithms should definitely be used.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be using `ecdf` in `StatsBase`.

```
using StatsBase
ecdf(samples)(sample)
# 0.54
```

In case this is needed many times, store the function.

```
f = ecdf(samples)
f(sample)
# 0.54
```

---

Benchmark

```
using BenchmarkTools
samples = collect(1:9999)
sample = 4321

@btime ecdf($samples)($sample)
#  23.900 μs (7 allocations: 156.47 KiB)

@btime f = ecdf($samples)
#  23.700 μs (7 allocations: 156.47 KiB)

@btime f($sample)
#  51.976 ns (2 allocations: 32 bytes)

@btime count(<=($sample), $samples)/length($samples) # @Dan Getz
#  793.814 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

sample = [100, 200, 300, 3000, 5000]
@btime f($sample)
#  19.500 μs (3 allocations: 288 bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

StatsBase also provides `quantilerank` and `percentilerank`.